# SQL Update Statement in c# with reserved-words

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, reserved-words

I have a problem with update statement:

In column names i have characters like: % , []. In "insert into" statement I just put that in quotation marks and worked. But can't execute this update statement:

```
UPDATE WIG_BANKI 
SET "Nazwa_spolki" = @BankNames, 
"Pakiet" = @Packet, 
"Udzial_w_portfelu[%]" = @ShareInPortfolio, 
"Udzial_w_obrocie[%]" = @ShareOfTurnover, 
"Wplyw_na_zmiane_indeksu[%]" = @ImpactOnChangeOfIndex, 
"Zmiana_kursu_spolki[%]" = @ExchangeRate, 
"Kurs[PLN]" = @PLN_ExchangeRate 
 WHERE "Nazwa_spolki" != @BankNames, 
       "Pakiet" != @Packet, 
       "Udzial_w_portfelu[%]" != @ShareInPortfolio, 
       "Udzial_w_obrocie[%]" != @ShareOfTurnover, 
       "Wplyw_na_zmiane_indeksu[%]" != @ImpactOnChangeOfIndex, 
       "Zmiana_kursu_spolki[%]" != @ExchangeRate, 
       "Kurs[PLN]" != @PLN_ExchangeRate
```

Then I execute the whole statement like this:

```
command.Parameters[Globals.columnsNamesArrayDB[i]].Value = array[i].ToString(); // here in for loop I set what is @BankNames etc.
command.CommandText = sbAllDataUpdate.ToString();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

then this message error shows

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

I have no idea how to correct it

Comment: Have you tried putting square brackets around the full names. Can you post what your command initializations looks like?

Comment: CREATE TABLE works and INSERT INTO  too so Command initialization is ok.
Can't put square brackets because in names I have square brackets and SQL gives error too.

Comment: I have no idea why this has 3 downvotes..  This is a well-asked question.

Comment: Beacuse in first form the whole update statement I put in one line and I think that was unreadable :) , my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

For `WHERE` you separate conditions with logical operators `AND OR`

```
 WHERE "Nazwa_spolki" != @BankNames AND
       "Pakiet" != @Packet AND
       "Udzial_w_portfelu[%]" != @ShareInPortfolio AND
       "Udzial_w_obrocie[%]" != @ShareOfTurnover AND
       "Wplyw_na_zmiane_indeksu[%]" != @ImpactOnChangeOfIndex AND 
       "Zmiana_kursu_spolki[%]" != @ExchangeRate AND 
       "Kurs[PLN]" != @PLN_ExchangeRate
```

Comment: I just don't know why you didn't get that from the extremely clear error message ;-)

Comment: Hey man, everyone who's learning sometimes thinks that he's problem is so complicated then realise that was so simple.

Comment: @janek9971: 


Sorry - I thought the smiley at the end would indicate I was joking - your SQL statement had so many comma's (mostly valid) - so reporting "Incorrect syntax near ','" is about as good as just reporting "Cant do this".

Comment: Now it's funny in that context. I thought that was smile of hatred :D

Comment: @janek9971: I think the SQL people want to make programmers suffer - MySQL error messages are just as helpful telling you there is an error near some string which may be repeated in the query - I have been using it for nearly 10 years & I still get error messages that I struggle with, it's not just beginners. Parameterized queries don't help because there is no way to see the full query so you can't easily "cut & paste" to run from the workbench.